# How to set conditional breakpoint in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb

My situation is here

```
(gdb) info break
Num Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1   breakpoint     keep y   0x0000db8f in -[Instrument getFormattedPriceString:] at Instrument.m:195
condition not yet parsed: (bool)[[self name] hasPrefix:@"7_"]
breakpoint already hit 1 time
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) p (bool)[[self name] hasPrefix:@"7_"]
$1 = false
(gdb) po name
2_YEAR
```

Despite that fact that condition evaluates correctly, my breakpoint breaks the execution every time. I see some peculiar statement `condition not yet parsed` here. Why GDB wouldn't parse my condition?

BTW I use xcode 3.2.6. Xcode4 doesn't even evaluate conditions like `a==1`

Answer (score 0):

Consider a temporary assert() or NSAssert(). It's much more reliable that debugger-based expression evaluation. Remove the assert() call once you don't need the breakpoint anymore. The syntax is:

```
#include <assert.h>

assert( !(expression_on_which_to_break));
```

Comment: `if(expression) _break();`? That's what assert, essentially, is.